# Multipage form in jQuery Mobile loses radio values

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-mobile

I have a form that spans multiple pages in jQuery Mobile. I'm using multi-page page with one set of form tags around all pages. This form was working fine before I separated it into multiple pages. Now it sends textbox data, but radio buttons' value is blank. Any way to fix this. Below is a sample of 2 pages with a radio set.

Thanks!

```
<div id="1" data-role="page" data-theme="c">
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed">
<a data-theme="a" class="ui-btn-right" href="#start" data-role="button" data-icon="back" data-transition="pop" data-rel="dialog" data-inline="true">Start Over</a></div>
<div data-role="content">

<form encoding='multipart/form-data' encType='multipart/form-data'>

<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
<legend><a href="#16pop" data-rel="popup" data-inline="true">Azimuth Verification</a></legend>
<input id="_fid_16_a" type="radio" name="_fid_16" value="Yes"/>
<label for="_fid_16_a">Yes</label><input id="_fid_16_b" type="radio" name="_fid_16" value="No"/>
<label for="_fid_16_b">No</label><input id="_fid_16_c" type="radio" name="_fid_16" value="N/A"/>
<label for="_fid_16_c">N/A</label>
</fieldset>
</div>

</div></div>


<div id="sigemail" data-role="page" data-theme="c">
<div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed">
<a data-theme="a" class="ui-btn-right" href="#start" data-role="button" data-icon="back" data-transition="pop" data-rel="dialog" data-inline="true">Start Over</a></div>
<div data-role="content">


<div data-role="fieldcontain"><label for="_fid_210">What email address would you like to use?</label><input type="text"  name="_fid_210" id="_fid_210" /></div>


<input type="button" value="Submit" data-theme="b" id="sendbtn" onclick="$.mobile.loading( 'show', {text: 'Sending... Please Wait', textVisible: true, theme: 'b'});" />

</form>

<script>
$(document).ready( function(){
    getLocationConstant();
    $('#sendbtn').click(function(){
        $.post(
          'fill.php', 
          $('form').serialize(), 
          function() {
            $.post(
              'https://www.quickbase.com/db/dbName?act=API_AddRecord', 
              $('form').serialize()
            );
            $.mobile.changePage('#successpop', {transition: 'pop', role: 'dialog'});
          }
        ).error(function errHandler() {$.mobile.changePage('#failpop', {transition: 'pop', role: 'dialog'})});
    });
});
</script>

</div></div>
```

Comment: Any reason why do you need to span a form across two pages?

Comment: It's actually 5 pages. The form has 95 radio selects and 95 comment boxes in total, so it needs to be broken up a bit. Any ideas why radios stopped sending post data? Thanks.

Comment: Ok, got it. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually a form across multiple pages works like a charm.
I made an example for you with both normal and jQuery submit.

There are three pages for that example:

- [multipage.html](http://jsfiddle.net/pmatseykanets/4CKkc/)
- [multipageresult.php](http://jsfiddle.net/pmatseykanets/YsRpe/)
- stub.php

The content of stub.php:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_REQUEST)) {
        print_r($_REQUEST);
    }
?>
```

Hope that will help.

Comment: Thanks perterm! That looks like it will work. I actually just ended up putting opening and closing form tags within each "page." I didn't realize that using ajax $('form').serialize() would accurately post all data from all forms on the page - including radio selects.